# How to get the number value from timedelta64

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get the number part from:

```
 numpy.timedelta64(4387946793,'ms')
```

I had tried the following code but I get "-2147483648" instead of "4387946793":

```
first_date = np.datetime64("2013-04-08 15:52:17.207")
last_date = np.datetime64("2013-05-29 10:44:44")

date_interv = last_date - first_date 

print(type(date_interv ))   ###   <class 'numpy.timedelta64'>

print(date_interv )         ###   4387946793 milliseconds

number_part = (date_interv  / np.timedelta64(1, 'ms')).astype(int)

print(number_part )         ###   -2147483648
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parameter `ms` inside np.datetime64(datetime,'ms') as second then do subtraction

```
first_date = np.datetime64("2013-04-08 15:52:17.207",'ms')
last_date = np.datetime64("2013-05-29 10:44:44",'ms')
a=last_date-first_date
b=a.astype('int')
type(b)
```

Comment: Thanks! but  want to extract just the number (4387947 ) i.e to have an integer variable for making some operations

Comment: @Nirmine i edited answer check now it converted to int

Comment: thanks I have fixe it I convert it by date_interv .astype(int)